# Как восстановить?

Tags: php, modx

Добрый день! Если удалить содержимое папки core, но при этом оставить cache, как можно восстановить систему?

Comment: Как это произошло?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все зависит от того, что в этой директории менялось. Если в ядро не вносились изменения, то должно быть достаточно:

1. Сделать резервную копию;
2. Восстановить `core` из дистрибутива;
3. Восстановить `core/config/config.inc.php` (там лежит пароль к базе);
4. Переустановить необходимые плагины (extras). Они будут храниться в `core/components`.

Comment: Хм. Опишите все-таки предысторию. Как вы оказались один на один с MODx? Куда делась директория `core`? Бэкап у провайдера спрашивали?